# Can't install apps from app store in Ubuntu 14.10 unity8

Tags: unity8

As the title says, I installed unity 8, but when I try to install apps from the app store, it always turns out failed. Do I need to install additional packages to install these "click" apps?

Comment: Why was this closed as "off-topic". Seems perfectly on topic to me!